# Custom Attribute to Ensure Encapsulation

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I'm beginning to look into custom attributes, and I've come up with the following idea: what if I could make an attribute which would restrict the use of a variable to the property it backed?

```
[RestrictToProperty("Foo")]
private object _foo;
public object Foo
{
    get { return _foo; }
    set
    {
        _foo = value;
        OnFooChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
public object NotFoo
{
    get { return _foo; }  // Warning
    set { _foo = value; } // Warning
}
public void Bar()
{
    _foo = new object();  // Warning
}

// Warning: 'MyClass._foo' should not be used outside of property 'Foo'
```

I believe it's possible, because `Obsolete` does a similar thing.

```
[Obsolete]
private object _foo;
public void Bar()
{
    _foo = new object(); // Warning: 'MyClass._foo' is obsolete
}
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to go about it, and can't find much beyond simple runtime attribute tutorials. Is this possible? If so, where would I start?

Comment: +1 for having the exact same thought :)  Unfortunately a custom FxCop rule is probably as close to this as you'll get (`Obsolete`'s behaviours can't be duplicated, unless you want to write your own c# compiler)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible. `ObsoleteAttribute` has a [special mention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664623(VS.71).aspx) in the C# specification regarding how the compiler itself responds to it.

You could implicity restrict a variables use to a single property by using [auto implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

```
public class Test
{
  public object Foo { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit:** If you wanted special logic handled independently in the getter and setter you could try the following code. This seems awfully obnoxious to me though.

```
public class Test
{

  private PrivateMembers Members { get; set; }

  public object Foo
  {
    get
    {
      return Members.Foo;
    }
    set
    {
      Members.Foo = value;
      // Do something else here.
    }
  }

  private class PrivateMembers
  {
    public object Foo { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's disappointing. See my comment to stakx about auto-implemented properties.

Comment: @Daniel: I edited my answer to provide another, albiet obnoxious, alternative.

Comment: I'm not sure how this does what I want... You'd still be able to access `Members.Foo` without the `Foo` property, wouldn't you..?

Comment: @Daniel: True, it definitely doesn't do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to write an [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) rule that would make this either an error or a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't possible.  You might want to explore [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) though, which is an Aspect-Oriented IL-weaver for .NET--basically it lets your source-code go through an extra layer of compilation which can inject all the extra ceremony.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly off-topic but you could (ab)use the `Obsolete` attribute to achieve what you need.

Mark the backing field as obsolete so that the compiler generates a warning when you try to access it, and then [suppress those warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys.aspx) within the property getter/setter. (The relevant warnings are [CS0612](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0h063ka.aspx) and [CS0618](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5ye6x1e.aspx).)

```
[Obsolete("Backing field should not be used outside of property")]
private object _foo;

public object Foo
{
    #pragma warning disable 612, 618
    get { return _foo; }
    set
    {
        _foo = value;
        OnFooChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    #pragma warning restore 612, 618
}
```

This does feel like a nasty hack, and really isn't something that I'd recommend. There are other, preferable alternatives. For example, custom FxCop rules, unit tests, good code commenting etc.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really interesting in a hack for it. I was just wondering if I could come up with an elegant solution. Thanks for the idea, though. It's a good example of what you *can* do.

Comment: That's actually pretty clever.