# Blocking access to private member variables? Force use of public properties?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm using .NET 2.0 so do not have access to automatic properties. So I must resort to the following way of coding private variables and public properties

```
private string m_hello = null;

public string Hello
{
     get{return m_hello;}
     set{m_hello = value;}
}
```

For methods of the containing class of the above private/public members, is there anyway to restrict access to the private variable? I do not like that I can either use m_hello or Hello.

Thanks.

Comment: One thing to note - even if you're targeting .NET 2.0, if you're using C# 3 to do so, you can still use automatic properties. They don't require any framework support.

Comment: @Jon -- that's probably important enough information to warrant an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @tvanfosson -- I agree, had no clue about that!

Comment: Not very relevant, but I'm surprised people are still using "m_". Not only is it recommended against (I personally prefer a leading "_" to indicate private variables), it's also ugly, although that may be personal opinion. Here's an article on .NET naming conventions and programming standards:

http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161401/custom-attribute-to-ensure-encapsulation

Comment: I was going to say the same thing Kevin however +1 for citing it too.

Comment: @Adam: You teased me! ;)

Comment: @Kevin: You've got to admit, though, that's one of the most subjective topics we could possibly discuss. It isn't like calling code *ever* sees these variable names. Once you've at least decided to distinguish your private members from public ones in some way by name, it's completely a matter of personal (and team) aesthetics.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Duly added and expanded slightly.

Comment: @Dan Tao: That is true. I'm not trying to force it upon him. If that's how it comes across, I do apologise. Merely trying to suggest what in my (and more people's) opinion is best practice. But as long as it works for them and it does its job; namely distinguishing the private from public members, keep on rocking that "m_".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there is not a way to do that, other than to simply follow your own convention and do this.Hello if you really need to go through your public property.

I don't see why you would need/want to do this either, as since it is your internal class,  you are the one in control of the code and you can define what/how it is used, so there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Woah! Sorry @Mitchel - I accidentally edited the wrong post. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: @Marc - did you get bit by the lovely random ordering feature?  I've had that happen more than once where I automatically assumed that my question was in the same position after an edit (or submission) and blindly clicked the edit button.  Doesn't help when the answer in that position starts with virtually the same text.

Answer (score 13):

As others have suggested this should be an answer...

You can still use automatic properties in C# 3 when targeting .NET 2.0, along with [quite a few other C# 3 features](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx). Unlike (say) expression trees, automatic properties don't need anything special from the CLR or the framework, beyond the `[CompilerGenerated]` attribute (which was introduced in .NET 2.0).

So if you're using VS2008 or VS2010, then it would be worth using an automatic property.

For what it's worth though, I'd like this ability too. I'd like to be able to scope variables within a property:

```
 public string Name
 {
     private string name;
     get { return name; }
     set { name = value; }
 }
```

I view this a bit like making a private variable readonly - it makes no difference to clients, but it helps to enforce correctness within the class code itself.

Comment: +1 - I agree completely with the privately scoped property variable.  I'd really like the ability both to have arbitrary code in the property methods **and** limit access to the backing field to the property only so that I don't accidentally avoid the "rules" in the getter/setter code.

Comment: Tangentially related, I'd like immutable automatic properties as well (settable via the constructor or initializer syntax) and then only gettable from there on in. Backed by a `readonly` field generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 8):

You can accomplish this via inheritance:

```
abstract class A // A is not instantiatable due to being abstract
{
    private string m_hello = null;

    public string Hello
    {
         get{return m_hello;}
         set{m_hello = value;}
    }
}

class B : A
{
    // B now cannot access the private variable, use B in your code instead of A
}
```

I am not claiming that this is good. Just that it can be done.

Answer (score 4):

No. Any method inside the class will have access to both.

Your team should standardize on which to use (Property or private variable).

Once you decide which to use, you could try to use a custom FxCop rule to enforce the standard.

Answer (score 1):

No, basically. Well, you *could* do something with compiler warnings via `[Obsolete]` and `#pragma`, but that would be excessive.

You could *probably* do it with tooling, but *eventually* you need to trust people not to do stupid things. After all, do you have special rules about:

```
while(true) { }
```

or do you just put that down to "don't be stupid"? ;p

Comment: `while(true)` plus `break` inside the loop's body is a perfectly valid programming construct. There is much worse things than that.

Comment: @ToxicAvenger - but *without* the `break`?

Comment: Anything could be justified by this line of reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

You should only access the property through the public Hello property.  This is the reason for this pattern.  If you add any functionality to the get or set, if you are accessing the private instance, you will introduce bugs into your code.   But the anwer is NO, you cannot prevent someone from calling the Private when they are inside your class changing your code.

Comment: Arguably, it can go both ways: you may well want to reference the backing field directly so that you aren't affected by any addition to the public property.  It would be a good idea to be consistent about this, however, and possibly a good idea to clearly identify backing variables that it's clear that a property is being bypassed.  For example, you could suffix them with `_Prop` or something like that.

Comment: I prefer consistency and just wanted to point out the reason for the pattern.  There's always a reason for every one off solution, doesn't make it best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I see nothing wrong with accessing the private member within the class. In fact that's what I typically do (unless there's logic within the property getter/setter that I always want to leverage).

It just makes sense to me: the code within the class *constitutes* that class's implementation; why hide an implementation from itself?

Here's an example of what I mean. Suppose I have some member, `m_denominator`, and I want it never to be zero:

```
private int m_denominator = 1;
public int Denominator
{
    get { return m_denominator; }
    set
    {
        if (value == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Denominator must not be zero.");
        m_denominator = value;
    }
}
```

I might say to myself: "OK, everywhere I set this value within this class, I should use `Denominator` to make sure I'm not setting it to zero." **But I'm completely in control of what I'm setting `Denominator` to -- I'm inside the class!** In *this* scenario, the point of the logic in the `Denominator` property is to protect the class from invalid values set by client code. There's no excuse for setting your internal state to some invalid value within the implementation of a class itself.

Of course this is not an absolute rule. There are surely times when using the property for its logic within a class may be a sensible choice as a protective measure; really, I'm just arguing that it's *not wrong* to access private members from within a class.

Comment: SO what happens when you come back to the code in 6 months to add important logic to the property setter?  All your class' internal code will now be bypassing the new implementations.

Comment: I prefer to default to using the property precisely because I don't want to keep track of places where the property does something special.  The optimizer will typically take care of optimizing the method call out anyway, at least for a simple accessor.  I'll only use the property when I know the property does something "special" and I want to avoid that for some particular purpose.

Comment: @Dr Herbie: But in my experience it's just as likely that you'll add logic to the property but *won't* want that logic to be executed on every access happening within the class -- only on accesses from external code. I've definitely worked with developers who added logic to their properties and all of a sudden they found some of their code was getting executed way more often than they intended. It's a judgement call, obviously; I'm just pointing out that there's a difference between hiding your implementation from the outside world and hiding it from... itself.

Comment: I find that highly suspect reasoning.  Typically, you put extra code into the property setter to enforce some dependency or business rule.  My experience is that you generally *don't* want to avoid this, even in the class.  There are certainly exceptions -- and I would reference the backing property in those cases -- but because they are exceptional I use the property in the default case rather than the other way around.  Referencing your example, I would say that in the initializer using the field directly is fine, but anywhere else in your class, you really do want to use the property

Comment: @tvanfosson: Hey, I'm not saying you're wrong. My perspective is basically this: the OP seems to be looking for a way to disallow access to a private member from within an implementation. I'm saying: this is not *necessarily* something you need to do. As for what kind of logic should or should not go into a property getter/setter, that's a different argument. In any case, we both seem willing to concede that *sometimes* one approach is reasonable and *sometimes* the other approach makes more sense; that's all I'm really trying to argue -- not which one is the exception and which is the rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself wanting to hide details from yourself, that may be a code smell that your class has too many responsibilities. Consider extracting one of the responsibilities into a new class.

Comment: Sometimes it's not "yourself" but there are other members of your team that could not follow the rules. I know, in theory everything has a simple solution but life is tough...

Comment: @JoeWhite: that's an interesting point of view. However fragmenting classes up to a level where each one has almost trivial responsibility sounds good in theory, but in practice can be a nightmare to understand in it's own right.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in `C#10`, or at least a [proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/140) for it, you can use semi-auto properties.

We can now use the `field` keyword in place of a backing property field.

So this:

```
private int _theNumber;
public int TheNumber 
{
    get => _theNumber;
    set => _theNumber = value;
}
```

Becomes this:

```
public int TheNumber
{
    get => field;
    set => field = value;
}
```

Granted in the example I provided an auto property would make more sense, but I wanted to show a simple example.