# Force use members over fields

Tags: c#

Is there a way to force usage of properties instead of private backing fields?

For example:

```
 //field
private string str;

// property
public string Str
{
  get { return this.str; }
  set { this.str = value; DoSomething(); }
}
```

Both members need to have read rights however only property should have write rights. How to achive that?

EDIT: I was talking about access rights inside the class. Not from outside.

Comment: You could make the backing field private so that nothing, apart from the instance itself, can access it.

Comment: @phuzi: You should ....

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the usage of "member" here. Which one do you want to be writable?

Comment: Inside the class I do not want to use this.str instead I want the.Str to be used.

Comment: @devhedgehog, then don't use it. It's internal to the class, so up to you to ensure it's used correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "Both variables need..."? There is only one variable here: `str`.

Comment: @devhedgehog But inside the class itself you can always access both, no matter if the modifier is `private` or `public`. If you only want to use `Str` inside the class, the only way to do so is to just do so :)

Comment: @InvisiblePanda there is no such a thing similar to readonly keyword?

Comment: @devhedgehog There is, but IIRC if you make `str` `readonly`, then you could not do `this.str = value` inside the setter anymore. `readonly` variables can only be assigned to in the declaration or in a constructor of your class. After that, you cannot change it anymore.

Comment: That is why I was asking for a similar keyword.. Is there one?

Comment: @devhedgehog: you should really clarify your question and the terms you use. [Members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173113.aspx) refer to _all_ members of a class like fields, properties or methods (even inherited).

Comment: I edited my question. Please take a look

Comment: Also, backing fields of properties should always be private, otherwise there's no reason to use properties at all. Only class members should be allowed to access the backing field directly.

Comment: I changed my question take a look please

Comment: @devhedgehog: so do you really want that only the setter of the property is allowed to modify the backing field and no other member of the class(like in a method)? That's not possible. Maybe your class should be refactored into multiple classes if you don't trust it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter why not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79396/discussion-between-tim-schmelter-and-dev-hedgehog).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming the reason that you don't want to be able to write directly to `str` within the class is because `DoSomething` is tightly coupled to its value changing. So to deal with that, use separation of concerns principles: create an internal class and make it solely responsible for ensuring that coupling is maintained:

```
internal class StrDoSomethingCoupler
{
    private readonly Action _doSomething;
    private string str;
    public StrDoSomethingCoupler(Action doSomething)
    {
        _doSomething = doSomething;
    }

    public string Str
    {
        get { return _str; }
        set { _str = value; _doSomething(); }
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly StrDoSomethingCoupler _coupler =
        new StrDoSomethingCoupler(DoSomething);

    ...

    public string Str
    {
        get { return _couple.Str; }
        set { _coupler.Str = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although not clear this is a good question. Let me rephrase it.

```
Class A
{
     //field
    private string _str;

    // member
    public string Str
    {
      get { return _str; }
      set { _str = value; DoSomething(); }
    }
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
       _str = "Dont access like this";
       Str= "Should access only like this";
    }
}
```

Sadly the answer is No, you cannot restrict the access of _str within Class A. Its only a coding practice you should follow, no inbuilt language feature that supports it. Reference - [Blocking access to private member variables? Force use of public properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265637/blocking-access-to-private-member-variables-force-use-of-public-properties)

There is a problem that I can see in the sample code. You are doing two things within the setter of Str.

i.e. `set { _str = value; DoSomething(); }` is a bad practice(Although some places its unavoidable, like `NotifyPropertyChanged()` in wpf).

So don't do that, better change that logic by separating DoSomething() from Str.set. Something like

```
Class A
{
     //field
    private string _str;

    // member
    public string Str
    {
      get { return _str; }
      private set { _str = value; }
    }
    private void DoSomething()
    {
       ..
       ..
    }
    public void UpdateStrAndDoSomething(string strValue)
    {
      Str = strValue;
      DoSomething();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why downvote? It would be helpful if you can point out the mistake.

Comment: Is having side affects from a setter really a violation of CQRS? Having any side affects from calling a getter definitely is, but side affects from setting should be expected.

Comment: @DavidArno I am sorry, I was in the assumption setter also violates the CQRS, hence quoted it. But the OP's problem is contributed because of having too many responsibilities within the Setter. So Am I right when I say it violates SRP?

Comment: I agree it's likely a case of too much code in one class and one or more separation of concerns problems that has both caused his desire to prevent `str` being directly modified and the need to couple `DoSomething` to it changing.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string _str;
public string Str
{
  get { return _str; }
  private set { _str = value; DoSomething();
}
```