# How to hide the backing field from the rest of the class

Tags: c#, properties, backing-field

Is there any way to enforce the rest of my class to access the property setter rather than the backing field? Consider the following clumsy code:

```
public class Brittle
{
    private string _somethingWorthProtecting;
    public string SomethingWorthProtecting
    {
        get { return _somethingWorthProtecting; }
        set
        {
            _somethingWorthProtecting = value;
            ReallyNeedToDoThisEverTimeTheValueChanges();
        }
    }

    public void OhDearWhatWasIThinking()
    {
        _somethingWorthProtecting = "Shooting myself in the foot here, aren't I?";
    }
}
```

As far as I know, C# does not provide any mechanism to prevent the class developer from making this mistake. (Auto-properties are clearly not an option in this situation.) Is there a design pattern or practice that can help safeguard against such inadvertant end-arounds?

Comment: If it is so important then it is worth to be unit tested

Comment: *"to prevent the class developer from making this mistake"* - that's overkill, seriously. If person modifying that class, need help like this, then rather don't let this person modify anything. Comments should suffice. From other side you can give this field *dedicated* name: `_doNotModifyMePlx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can move that logic to an abstract base class:

```
public abstract class Brittle
{
    private string _somethingWorthProtecting;
    public string SomethingWorthProtecting 
    {
        get { return _somethingWorthProtecting; }
        set
        {
            _somethingWorthProtecting = value;
            ReallyNeedToDoThisEverTimeTheValueChanges();
        }
    }

    //.....
}
```

then you can be sure no one will instantiate this class, and derived classes will not be able to access the private field.

```
public class BrittleDerived : Brittle
{
     public void DoSomething() 
     {
        // cannot access _somethingWorthProtecting;
     }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of the answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3265833/993547 :) Two minds thinking the same.

Comment: This solution gives nothing. One month later someone will try to add new functionality to the base class, and problem will back.

Comment: I mean, if someone has access to your codebase, there's only so many failsafes you can put in.  If they want to destroy your code they can.